# VB6 custom implicit string conversion

Tags: vb6

Is there any way how to provide implicit string conversion for custom class in VB6? All materials I've found say it is not possible. But it somehow works with Excel object `Range`:

```
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Worksheets("test").Range("A1")
    Dim s1 As String
    s1 = r.Address      ' "$A$1"
    Dim s2 As String
    s2 = r.Value        ' "test"
    Dim s3 As String
    s3 = r              ' "test"
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to set the default method for a class.  If so, take a look at this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240803(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: +1 @GMastros. The solution is to create a string property which returns the correct string, and mark that property as the default property for the class as explained GMastros's link